# Jquery / Phonegap / Android not supported gif ?

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, gif

I want to use loading gif in my project. I can wrote this in jquery with show() and hide() methods. It works normally. But when i deploy my project with phonegap on eclipse, Loading gif doesn't appear. Android doesn't support gif type. How can i use it on android device?

Answer (score 0):

### Animated gif supported was added in android 2.2 (Froyo)

However it seems to be turned of on most devices. If you are interested you can jump into more details: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3422

I am on Nexus 4 with android 4.4 (KitKat) and gif's are animated for me (very slow however).

Phonegap bundles your html5+js into a apk file and displays your project in a embedded webview. So basically your gif should be animated because it is displayed in a browser.

However phonegap's webview seems to disable the animated gif support (not sure).

### You could use one of this workarounds:

- [**jQuery sprite animation**](http://addyosmani.com/blog/jquery-sprite-animation/)
- [**Animated JS Canvas**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Basic_animations#An_animated_solar_system)